# Terminal Localhost hotkey or shortcut please

Tags: python, web-services, terminal

I created a web application which is running on localhost.

MacBook-Pro:app username$ python apiai.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/
 * Restarting with reloader

How do I open http://127.0.0.1:8000/ through terminal directly?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Open the browser? That wouldn't be a programming question.

Comment: Insufficient data. What do you mean "open... through terminal directly"? You can open a URL via a program in many ways. For example, from an interactive shell session or shell script you can do so using the programs `wget` or `curl`. If you want to open a URL from a python program I recommend the `requests` module.

Answer (score 0):

Use the open command in terminal:

```
open http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

This should open in your default browser

Comment: is there a hotkey for that instead of typing all of that?

Comment: @Sheng Liu you asked how to open a URL on macOS from an interactive shell (i.e., "terminal"). This answer you commented on tells you exactly how to do that. So apparently your question is something other than what you stated.